# Error message doesn't display correctly

Tags: java, message

I'm trying to make dialog that will display an error message whenever I make wrong move in my scrabble game. So in Problem.java, I make it like this

```
class Problem
{
   Problem(String s)
  {
        message = s;
  }
}
```

So I write code to display the warning like this :

```
    void displayProblem(Problem p)
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,p, "WARNING!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I expect error message when I don't put tile something like this :
"no tiles placed"
just like what's in the code but it ended up like this :

[image]

What's wrong with my code anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to pass `p.message` to the dialog or override Problem's `toString()` method and return `message` there. What you're seeing is the output of standard `toString()`, i.e. class name + instance id.

Comment: thanks a lot, and sorry because i'm afraid if i don't give enough detail. I'm quite new here

Comment: @user3762162 no, you were providing too many details, leaving out the blocks for `humanMove`, `checkMove` and `check` would result in a reasonably sized question without any relevant part missing ;) - And since you're new here I added a link with some tips on how to maximise your chances of getting answers. :)

Comment: Ok, fixed. I won't repeat the mistake again next time. thank you :D